# Problems with gascoigne 3d on WSL2

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I am trying to install Gascoigne 3D on my local computer. I use WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04. For installing Gasgoicne 3D I followed this website [https://www.math.uni-magdeburg.de/~richter/gascoigne/index.php?show=downloadinstallation](https://www.math.uni-magdeburg.de/%7Erichter/gascoigne/index.php?show=downloadinstallation)
Everything worked. Now I want to install the tutorial ([https://www.math.uni-magdeburg.de/~richter/gascoigne/index.php?show=documentationtutorial](https://www.math.uni-magdeburg.de/%7Erichter/gascoigne/index.php?show=documentationtutorial)), which works as well. But once I want to run problem 1 I get a Segmentation fault.

My output looks like this:

```
(base) tasha@laptop:~/GAS/gascoigne-tutorial/Problems/problem1$ ../../../bin-tutorial/problem1
Warning: DirichletData without colors and comp_on_color
Warning: DirichletData without colors and comp_on_color
2D Mesh: 57 nodes, 34 lines, 40 quads
ProjectBoundary not written

================== 1 ================ [l,n,c] 2 708 640
==================================================
Solver:                   StdSolver
Discretization:           CG Discretization
DirichletData:            Bench
BoundaryManager:          Std
ComponentInformation:     ComponentInformationBase
==================================================
[Results/solve.00000.vtk]
   0: 3.07e-02
Segmentation fault
```

I assume that there might be a problem with my WSL2 configuration.

Cheers,
Tasha

Comment: Can you confirm that you are really using WSL2 by typing `wsl -l -v` in PowerShell or cmd?  I often find that people *think* their instance is WSL2 just because they have WSL2 enabled on Windows.  But the distribution/instance still ended up as WSL1 for one reason or another when installed.

Comment: sure :) 

`PS C:\Users\tasha> wsl -l -v
  NAME            STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu-20.04    Running         2
PS C:\Users\tasha>`

Comment: I'm really not an expert here, so hopefully someone can come along with a more definitive answer.  Did you install all of the listed dependencies (are they really required?).  I see that [SUITESPARSE](http://faculty.cse.tamu.edu/davis/suitesparse.html), which is listed as a dependency, mentions that it is CUDA-accelerated, but WSL doesn't (yet) have CUDA support.  That functionality is currently only enabled in Windows Insider (preview) builds.  Or it could be that the SUITESPARSE CUDA support is optional.  Again, not sure if this is the reason for your error or not.  Just hypothesizing.